# Java image/map object

Tags: java, image, swt

Using Java and SWT, I am trying to display a map (provided as an image) and mark points on it. First idea is to use a canvas, draw the image (scaled to the largest possible size for this canvas) and then draw the markings (fixed size) to the scaled coordinates. However I would also like to zoom in and move the image, and would prefer not to develop all this functionality from scratch. However I am not having much luck finding an existing solution, though I would guess there should be something out there.

The criteria would be:

- based on SWT (or compatible)
- allows exchange of the image (possibly with different sizes)
- handles user interaction (selection a point on the image, zooming in/out of the image)

Does anybody know a standard/common solution?

Comment: Google is a solution you are looking for.

Comment: @nikpon I tried to ask them, but when I called they refused to help me :-(

Comment: I didn't have time yet to fully check out these links, but maybe they are useful to you: http://udig.github.io/ (Some presentation slides including examples and useful resources are [here](http://prezi.com/wyopic4sinhg/geographic-scripting-in-udig-user-friendly-desktop-internet-gis/)), and https://github.com/erdalkaraca/geoff

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen Thanks, but this is way too specific. I am not using a large map or complex data, basically it's just a simple image that I want to mark something on. It may not even be a map, the same thing could be used for zooming into a painting, or any other image.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex your system will potentially grow, maybe using [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/) is an option.

The whole rendering is done on SWT.Canvas and it provides Zooming/Scrolling/Moving out of the Box. 
Downside: Its dependant on RCP, so this is likely to be only an option if you need to build an otherwise complex application - in all other cases GEF will be quite heavyweight to set up.